# Twig - Why does it not allow us to set object / array values?

Tags: arrays, symfony, object, twig

I'm extremely confused by the decision of Twig to not allow setting values of arrays and object properties via `set`.

For example, the following code will error out:

`{% set entry.depth = 1 %}`

Will result in the error:

`Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("end of statement block" expected)`

Also the following way will also error (which I know twig doesn't prefer to use):

`{% set entry['depth'] = 1 %}`

So this effectively means we're unable to change properties of objects and arrays. I quite frankly find this bizarre.

Can someone please explain the decision behind this? Maybe if I get a technical reason why it's not possible it might make it less baffling.

Edit: Thanks for the solution, I was more after the reasoning behind the fact you have to use merge rather than just simply being able to override variables.

Answer (score 8):

Twig's a bit weird in this regard. You'll need to use the `merge` filter for this.

```
{% set entry = entry|merge({'depth': 1}) %}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for (associative) arrays, for an object I get `The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "object" as first argument`